# Does Visual Studio local machine run on a different resolution?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, winrt-xaml

I'm working on a pretty basic Windows app and I was hoping to programmatically resize items based on the resolution (of the app).  I am using this code which was suggested on another thread.

```
var bounds = Window.Current.Bounds;
double height = bounds.Height;
double width = bounds.Width;
```

I'm outputting the height and width to a textbox for testing and the numbers don't look quite right, they are both off by a fixed amount.  I suspect this might be something simple since my simulator seems to run fine.  But when I run it on my local machine (a Surface Pro 3), the resolution is completely off.  I'm just wondering if it's because Visual Studio is running a build meant for another resolution or something like that?

Thanks

Comment: Window.Current.Bounds returns effective pixels so you're probably just seeing the effect of scaling.

Comment: So should I be worried about it?  I mean everything is working fine in the simulator in any resolution.  If I compile it and publish it, will it work with my Surface Pro 3?

Comment: I don't have enough details to answer that, but in general your app should handle different resolutions and scale factors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

user3787031! 
There are 3 scale factors for Windows 8.1 applications - 100%, 140% and 180%.
For Windows 10 apps -there are more scale factors.
For example if your desktop is 23 inch and have a resolution 1920x1080 - then you have a 100% scale.
If you have a tablet 12 inch and resolution 2160x1440 then you have a 150% scale. You can see resolutions and scales in emulator.
If you need same quality images - you should create different size images with postfix scale and use code like this:

```
                ResolutionScale resolutionScale = DisplayInformation.GetForCurrentView().ResolutionScale;
            Uri uri = null;
            switch (resolutionScale)
            {
                case ResolutionScale.Scale100Percent:
                    uri = new Uri("ms-appx:///images/scale-100/girl.jpg");
                    break;
                case ResolutionScale.Scale140Percent:
                    uri = new Uri("ms-appx:///images/scale-140/girl.png");
                    break;
                case ResolutionScale.Scale180Percent:
                    uri = new Uri("ms-appx:///images/scale-180/girl.png");
                    break;
            }
   image.Source = new BitmapImage(uri);
```

For example if image scale-100 is 100px wide then image scale-140 is 140px wide.
If you want to get real screen size - use this:

```
public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
            this.SizeChanged += MainPage_SizeChanged;
        }

        void MainPage_SizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e) 
        { 
            if (e.NewSize.Width < 500) 
                { 
                    grdMain.Width=475; 
                } 
                else 
                { 
                      grdMain.Width=1000; 
                } 
            } 
       }
       /// ...
```

e.NewSize.Width - is a real screen width (not in effective pixels)

Comment: Thanks that was a great explanation.  Had to redo the code, but in the end it worked out pretty well.